# $E[XY]-E[X^2]-E[Y^2]$, is there any special property?

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value, joint-distribution

Given probability distributions of random variable $X,Y$, without any additional assumptions, is there any nice representation or properties of the combination $E[XY]-E[X^2]-E[Y^2]$? If not, is there any nice feature that arises with some additional assumptions? I tried to rewrite as covariance and variance, but they don’t necessarily fall into a nice form

Comment: The expression seems nice enough to me. What are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It’s a bit hard to describe, but this is physics application. Somehow, taking the difference seems to give unusual property, whereas individual terms dont (as written, they seem like just number, but there is an additional argument for each of the term, and the difference behaves interesting as a function of this argument). I was wondering if there’s any potential explanation from statistics for the behavior

Comment: Can you describe the unusual property further?

Comment: Assuming the second moments are finite, you can say it is negative except in the trivial case where $X$ and $Y$ are both almost surely zero.  Clearly it scales (with the square of $X$ and $Y$) so the magnitude of the number is not particularly meaningful in itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you ask about $E[Q(X,Y)]$ where

$$Q(x,y) = q_{xx}x^2 + q_{yy}y^2 + 2q_{xy}xy = \pmatrix{x&y}\pmatrix{q_{xx}&q_{xy}\\q_{xy}&q_{yy}}\pmatrix{x\\y} = \pmatrix{x&y}\mathbb Q \pmatrix{x\\y}$$

is a *homogeneous quadratic form* that is *represented* by the symmetric matrix $\mathbb Q.$  The question concerns the case $q_{xx}=q_{yy}=-1,$ $q_{xy}=1/2.$

Such forms can be diagonalized with *orthogonal transformations*.  That is, there exists an orthogonal matrix $\mathbb O$ ($\mathbb O^\prime \mathbb O = \mathbb I_2$) for which

$$\mathbb O^\prime\, \mathbb Q\, \mathbb O = \pmatrix{\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2}.$$

Therefore, in terms of the linearly transformed variables

$$\pmatrix{U\\V} = \mathbb O^\prime\pmatrix{X\\Y},$$

for which

$$\pmatrix{X\\Y} = \mathbb O \pmatrix{U\\V}\quad\text{and}\quad \pmatrix{X&Y} = \pmatrix{U&V}\mathbb O^\prime$$

(by virtue of the orthogonality of $\mathbb O$), we have

$$\pmatrix{X&Y}\mathbb Q \pmatrix{X\\Y} = \pmatrix{U&V}\mathbb O^\prime\,\mathbb Q\,\mathbb O \pmatrix{U\\V} = \lambda_1 U^2 + \lambda_2 V^2.$$

Linearity of expectation implies

$$E\left[Q(X,Y)\right] = E\left[\pmatrix{X&Y}\mathbb Q \pmatrix{X\\Y}\right] = \lambda_1 E[U^2] + \lambda_2 E[V^2].$$

**This generally gives the simplest possible interpretation of $Q:$** it's a weighted sum (or difference) of squares of variables that themselves are simply linear combinations of the original variables.  For the form in the question, you can check that $\lambda_1=-1/2$ and $\lambda_2=-3/2$ with

$$U = (X+Y)/\sqrt{2}\quad\text{and}\quad V = (X-Y)/\sqrt{2}.$$

Because all the *eigenvalues* $\lambda_i$ are negative, this is a *negative-definite* form: its value is always negative except when $Q$ is evaluated at $(0,0),$ where necessarily the value will be zero.

#### Comments

*No* assumptions are needed for these calculations apart from the existence of the moments in question (which is equivalent to $X$ and $Y$ each having finite variance).

I have italicized all relevant technical terms that will be useful for further research into the mathematics of quadratic forms.